# Remove all my changes from my fork on BitBucket and import the remote repository that I forked?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have forked a BitBucket project into my own BitBucket account. I have made some changes that are no longer relevant. The project that I created my fork from (I think the term is remote repository) has also been updated.

Can I delete all my changes and update my fork to the latest version of the remote repository?

I would prefer to do this directly in BitBucket. In addition to BitBucket I also use SourceTree.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fork the original project a second time.

1. Go to the original project.
2. Hover over the "..." button
3. Click "Fork"
4. Give your fork a different name (maybe?)
5. Click "Fork repository" button.

You may want to delete the first fork first, then you can just re-use its name.